# How to develop the the Backward Euler method for a State Space

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, numerical-methods

I have been trying to develop to solve a state space model in discrete time.
I have the following equation for my state space:
$$\dot{x} = Ax + Bu, $$

I am developping the equation, but I do not understand why I don't have the right form as equations 7 and 8 in this website ([link](https://aleksandarhaber.com/introduction-to-subspace-system-identification-system-identification-tutorial/)):
$$
\dot{x} = \frac{dx}{dt} = f(x, t) \\
\implies \frac{x_{n} - x_{n-1}}{h} = f(x_n, t_n) \\
\implies \frac{x_{n} - x_{n-1}}{h} = Ax_n + Bu_n \\
\implies x_n - x_{n-1} = hAx_n + hBu_n \\
\implies (I - hA)x_n = x_{n-1} + hBu_n \\
\implies \boxed{x_n = (I-hA)^{-1}x_{n-1} + (I-hA)^{-1}hBu_n} 
$$

I should obtain $ x_n = (I-hA)^{-1}x_{n-1} + hABu_{n-1} $ according to [equation 8 here](https://aleksandarhaber.com/introduction-to-subspace-system-identification-system-identification-tutorial/).

Comment: Please make the question self contained; perhaps by typing out the _right form_ of the equation from the website or by posting a screenshot containing only the relevant portions.

Comment: In the above _derivation_, it is not clear how line 3 is obtained from line 2 and how a negative sign appeared in line 6.

Comment: @AJN Oups my bad for line 6 I made a mistake in writing. 
For line 3 I just took $\dot{x} = Ax + Bu$ from the state space equations.

Answer (score 0):

1. The resource contains *two distinct* symbols; $A_c$ and $A = (I-hA_c)^{-1}$. So, $h \color{red}{A} Bu_{n-1}$ in equation (8) expands to $h \color{red}{(I-hA_c)^{-1}} Bu_{n-1}$
2. Equation (7) in linked page has $B_c u_{k \color{red}{-1}}$. You appear to have used $B u_{n}$.

These are the only two differences I could find.

Comment: Thank you, what is wrong in my development that leads me to $u_{n}$ instead of $u_{n-1}$ as derived in the linked source ?

Comment: Since that step in the derivation doesn't involve any mathematical logic. From line 2 to 3, it is more of an assumption or definition rather than logic. So nothing wrong per se, I think. If you could have replaced $f$ by $\dots B u_{k-1}$ instead.

Answer (score 0):

The state space model is defined as

$$\dot{x}=A_c\,x +B_c\,u$$
And he is replacing $\dot{x}=u$ using the Backward Euler method, that is $u_k = \frac{x_k - x_{k-1}}{h}$, where h is the discretization time step. Thus we have:

$$\frac{x_k - x_{k-1}}{h} = A_c\,x +B_c\,u $$

As you noticed he is somehow combining discrete time and continous time, but he claims that an approximation is done through equation (7), i.e.

$$\frac{x_k - x_{k-1}}{h} = A_c\,x +B_c\,u  \approx A_c\,x_k + B_c\,u_{k-1}$$

Unfortunately is not clear from where he got this approximation, and personally I would not use that approximation. Anyway, (and doing in his way) the rest is quite easy to solve
\begin{equation}
x_k - x_{k-1} = h\,Ac\,x_k + h\,B_c\,u_{k-1} \\
          x_k =(I-h\,Ac)^{-1}\,x_{k-1} + (I-h\,Ac)^{-1} h B_c\,u_{k-1}\\
x_k =(I-h\,Ac)^{-1}\,x_{k-1} + h\,(I-h\,Ac)^{-1}\,B_c\,u_{k-1}
\end{equation}
Then, we define $A := (I-h\,Ac)^{-1}$ and replace, that is
$$x_k = A\,x_{k-1} + h\,A\,B_c\,u_{k-1}$$
last step we define $B:= h\,A\,B_c $ giving us equation (8), i.e.
$$x_k = A\,x_{k-1} + B\,u_{k-1}$$